# Merge [quartus] and [quartus-ii] tags?

Tags: support, tag-cleanup

I think we should merge [quartus](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quartus) and [quartus-ii](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quartus-ii) tags. Both refer to FPGA/ASIC design software from Altera. Quartus II has been around since about 2003, and recently (since version 15.1) was re-branded to Quartus Prime. I've never seen older versions of Quartus (without the "II").

In any case, most features of the software remained similar throughout the years, so I believe that questions about it would benefit from being kept together. IMO the most reasonable thing to do is to keep [quartus](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quartus) and make [quartus-ii](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quartus-ii) its synonym, but I'm sure there are more experienced users here which know what is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I second the vote for yes. Given that it has been Quartus II since at least 2002 (possibly earlier), there is really no difference between the two.

I'm not sure if it was necessary or not, but I added [quartus-ii](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quartus-ii) as a suggested [tag synonym](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/quartus/synonyms) of [quartus](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quartus).

Answer (score 1):

I vote yes, it would be easier to find of and filter questions. Software is always changing we don't need to keep track of version numbers. I've found that some older questions don't apply to the newer versions, but you should mention what version your using OR a reader could look at the time stamp on the question.